# Show views depending on radio button selection

Tags: java, android, radio-button

Thank you for understanding my lack of English skills.

I am working on an android app in java. Is there a way to change the group of 6 buttons according to the selection of A Radio button and B Radio button?

[image][image]

I didn't try because I didn't have a good idea.

Comment: You may change buttons text based on selected radio ... Where is the problem ?

Comment: Each button has a different function.

Comment: and ? ... you can have in onClick `if(radio1checked) { doButtonXCode1() } else { doButtonXCode2() }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply add in you XML layout two different radio groups, with their personal ID.
So, based on check selected, you hide and show the correct radio-groups.

Example:

```
radioA.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
//show groupA
//hide groupB
       }
   }
);     



radioB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
    //show groupB
    //hide groupA
           }
       }
    );
```